# Write a one-off or anonymous class in Python?

Tags: python, class, anonymous-class

I frequently have simple classes which I'll only ever want a single instance of. As a simple example:

```
import datetime
import sys

class PS1(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        return str(now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

sys.ps1 = PS1()
```

Is there a way that I could somehow combine the definition and instantiation into a single step and achieve the same results?

As another example, just as something that is simple enough to understand.

```
class Example(object):
    def methodOne(self, a, b):
        return a + b

    def methodTwo(self, a, b):
        return a * b

example = Example()
```

I googled around and found nothing (lots of people throwing around the words `one-off` and `anonymous` but nobody seems to be talking about the same thing I am). I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
example = class(object):
    def methodOne(self, a, b):
        return a + b

    def methodTwo(self, a, b):
        return a * b
```

I realize I don't gain much, just one line I don't have to type plus one fewer things in my namespace, so I understand if this doesn't exist.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with these classes?  The more I look at this, the more this looks like an XY problem stemming from an overuse/misuse of classes in Python.  Usually, if you find yourself wanting to create a class with only a single instance, you should really be looking at using a more basic container or possibly a module instead.  Stateless classes that just contain utility methods are basically an anti-pattern in Python, and that looks like what you are building here.

Comment: @SilasRay - the nature of `sys.ps1` (and `sys.ps2`) requires me to pass in an instance of a class, which will only ever have `__repr__` called on it. I don't like having to add the class to my namespace as it just clutters it when I'm looking through debugger output. I realize such a feature would have limited cases where it would be a good idea, so I understand if it simply isn't doable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you don't see this often because it's really hard to read, but ...

```
sys.ps1 = type('PS1', (object,), {'__repr__': lambda self: datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')})()
```

would do the trick here...

I use `type` to dynmically create a class (the arguments are name, base classes, class dictionary).  The class dictionary just consists of a single function `__repr__` in this case.

Hopefully we can agree that the full format is much easier to grok and use ;-).

Comment: This won't work if the class has any methods that aren't lambda-izable.

Comment: @BrenBarn -- Well, you _could_ always define those as regular functions separately.  In any event, doing this is a bad idea anyway.  I don't really see the problem with the original code (which is why my answer is littered with comments like "this is hard to read", etc.)

Comment: @BrenBarn Well, I believe you can "lambda-ize" *any* method. However the result may be completely unreadable.

Comment: Yeah.  I don't think this kind of solution is actually what's being asked for, though.  His attempt shows that he's not looking for a one-liner --- he still wants the class definition to be in full form, he just doesn't want that extra line to instantiate it.  I agree that there's not much reason to care about that one extra line.

Comment: Interesting to see this is possible, albeit impossible to read. Will this still add PS1 to my namespace? I'll accept the answer if it doesn't, because it accomplishes both goals of having fewer lines and not polluting the namespace. Really though, the namespace one strikes me as more important. The idea behind fewer lines is improved readability, but more columns is worse than more lines in this case.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't.  You could easily do `PS1 = type(...)()` and then `sys.ps1 = PS1` if you wanted to add PS1 to the namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple class decorator to replace the class with an instance of it:

```
def instantiator(cls):
    return cls()
```

Then use it like this:

```
@instantiator
class PS1(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        return str(now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

Then:

```
>>> PS1
11:53:37
```

If you do this, you might want to make the class name lowercase, since it will ultimately be used to name an instance, not a class.

This still requires an extra line, but not an extra name in the namespace.

If you *really* wanted to, you could write a metaclass that does the same thing, but automatically.  However, I don't really think this would save much effort over just instantiating the class manually, and it would definitely make the code more complex and difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

*(@mgilson's answer achieves what you're looking for in the most direct way. I second him on the opinion your original code is better than any of the answers here)*

A simpler, more readable alternative, only if you don't need to use any special functions (e.g. `__repr__`), just use a dict of functions (playing the role of the methods):

```
fake_obj = dict(method_one = lambda a,b: a+b, method_two = lambda a,b: a*b)
```

Comment: The code posted in the question is the answer that I would go with ;-)

Comment: @mgilson Well, no one forced you to post an inferior answer ;-) I absolutely agree.

Comment: I mostly posted an inferior answer to demonstrate how ugly it actually is ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a metaclass, so you can still use prettier syntax in comparison to @mgilson's answer.

```
class OneOff(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        klass = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        return klass()

class PS1(object):
    __metaclass__ = OneOff

    ...
```

However, I'm with the others saying that I'm not sure this is a great idea.  I did something like this once, but it was for a very specific usecase, and I'd really think about exploring other avenues first.  Also, this looks an awful lot like a singleton/borg, so maybe that would be the better way for you to go.

Comment: I really don't see what you gain here above `class PS1(object): ...` and then `PS1 = PS1()` -- This has the exact same namespace implications, same number of lines and no metaclass magic to trip over.

Comment: @mgilson I agree, but it's what OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this in python. One is to instantiate a singleton object which can be done with a decorator, another is to make the class itself the used object with class methods and class variables.

The first option (singleton) looks like this:

```
def apply_class(*args, **kwargs):
    def myclass(c):
        c(*args,**kwargs)
    return myclass

@apply_class(5)
class mysingleton(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        print x
```

The second option (class methods/variables) looks like this:

```
class mysingleton:
    myvariable = 5
    @classmethod
    def mymethod(cls):
        print cls.myvariable
```